# How to make child_process.exec() run .bat file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, batch-file

I am asking a strange question, but I hope this helps other people if they encounter a similar problem.

I've got regular commands.bat file and I want node to run (execute) this file. So, I've done something like that:

```
let exec = require ('child_process').exec;
let myFancyProcess = await exec('commands.bat', function(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work at all.

Node.js docs says that `.exec()` expects command or executable as first parameter.

Probably, there is better way to run .bat file and I will appreciate it if you share this knowledge with me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to call the interpreter and pass the name of the batch script as an argument.

Comment: Please specify, what kind of interpreter?

Comment: `cmd /C call commands.bat`…

Comment: Thanks, I've tried:
`exec('cmd', ['/C', 'call', 'commands.bat'], function(error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log(stdout);
}); ` 
but it doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record. Correct way to run *.bat file: 
`exec('call commands.bat');`

Answer (score 0):

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
exec(`<absolute path, eg: C:/users/files>/<filename>.bat`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
                    return
                }

                if (stderr) {
                    console.error(`exec stderr: ${stderr}`);
                    return
                }
                console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
            })
```